# Will the OAuth 2.0 token for Lightning Sync copied from/to salesforce sandbox environment?

Tags: deployment, change-set, sandbox-refresh, sync, office-365

We are going to connect salesforce Lightning Sync via OAuth 2.0 to our O365 applications.

1. Will the issued OAuth Token be copied to a sandbox environment, if already present in the productive environment?
2. Will an existing OAuth Token, in the sandbox system, get copied to the productive Org, if we create a new Deploy Change Set?

Background is, we have an existing Salesforce Org which does not have an Lightning Sync OAuth Token yet. We want to get the token to be created for our sandbox system, test it, and deploy the new change set (including the token) to the original Org.

Thanks, kind regards.

Comment: Are you able to log-in to the sandbox using OAuth? Have you configured OAuth in the Sandbox? Lightning Sync for Outlook allows you to sync Contacts, Events, and Tasks and should have no impact on the use of Change Sets. But, you should be able to test Lightning Sync in your Sandbox.

Comment: The question is not if it is possible to test when a new token is entered. My question is, will the issued token permission be transfered to my productive Org or do I have to issue a new Token afterwards, when transfering the objects structures and permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the documentation, you do not want to try to deploy Lightning Sync to your production org from a Sandbox. Only use the Sandbox for testing Lightning Sync features in your organization. Lightning Sync should be installed directly into your production org. For more on this, see [Considerations for Companies With Multiple Salesforce Organizations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=exchange_sync_admin_config_avoid_sync.htm&type=5). In particular, note the following:

> You’re using multiple organizations if you either:
>
> - Test new features in a sandbox organization before setting up the feature in your live organization.
> - Maintain separate Salesforce organizations for different divisions of your company.

and

> We don’t recommend marking a Lightning Sync configuration as inactive to prevent data from syncing between your Salesforce organizations. While marking a configuration as inactive prevents it from syncing a user’s data, you risk forgetting that user is included in multiple Lightning Sync configurations, and marking the configuration as active later.
>
> **EXAMPLE**
>
> You’re testing Lightning Sync features in your sandbox organization, so you add user Marianne Schumacher to a Lightning Sync configuration in the sandbox organization. After you’re satisfied with how you’ve set up Lightning Sync features for Marianne, you’re ready to add her to a Lightning Sync configuration in your live organization.
>
> Before you add Marianne to a Lightning Sync configuration in your live organization, remove her from the configuration in your sandbox organization. Otherwise, Lightning Sync can sync contacts and events between Marianne’s email application, the sandbox organization, and the live organization, saving test and live data to all three data sources.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing point / feature note why not to do that!